# Prevent push to next view controller twice

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I Would like push to another view controller, but when you hit the button few times, it will push to the view controller two times or more. How to prevent push many times happened.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
         let vc: MyOrderDetailsViewController? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orderDetailsVC") as? MyOrderDetailsViewController
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: don't use async task....

Comment: disable button after first time push

Comment: @Nur || do you mean when you press button it shows second controller 2 times? In general all UI related work happens on main queue , so there is not need to create one, its already happening on main queue. I would suggest you to check storyboard once, have you connected segue from there as well?

Answer (score -3):

Async method creates thread & push VC in background so Don't use Async method to push any view controller...

It will run your code as much time as you pressed, instead use the follow code.. this won't allow you to again click or rerun the same code till it completes the task..

```
func pushTap()
{
     let vc: MyOrderDetailsViewController? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "orderDetailsVC") as? MyOrderDetailsViewController
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Hope this helps.. Thanks

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: What happens if we need to do it asynchronously?